# Express.js method is called twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/api/questions/:group/:limit', function(req, res) {
  var group = req.params.group;
  var limit = req.params.limit;
  console.log('123');

    return QuestionModel.find({group: group})
                        .sort({ creation_timestamp: -1 })
                        .limit(limit)
                        .exec(function(err, questions) {
                            if(!err) {
                                return res.send( { status: 'OK', result: questions });
                            } else {
                                res.statusCode = 500;
                                log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
                                return res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
                            }
                        });
});
```

When I open `localhost:5000/api/questions/js/5` in the browser I can see that the method was called twice:

```
123
123
```

If I rewrite this method like this the method is called only once time:

```
app.get('/api/questions/:group/:limit', function(req, res) {
  var group = req.params.group;
  var limit = req.params.limit;
  console.log('123');
  return;
});
```

Why in the first case the method is called twice and how can I avoid this ?

**Updated**: it works twice in Chrome, but only once in Safari and Firefox.  No messages in browser console.

Comment: Is the query taking a very long time and the browser is initiating a retry?

Comment: No, it takes less than 2 seconds

Comment: I have problem only in Chrome. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason - Web Technology Notifier Extension for Google Chrome.